# Make sidebar responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am working on a new site at the moment, and I'm wondering how I would go about making the sidebar responsive, meaning that:

- it moves from the left to the top (not sticky);
- the links turn into a hamburger icon;
- when the hamburger icon is tapped, a full-screen menu appears (transparent colour), withthe available links centered on the screen, and an "X" to dismiss the menu in the top right;
- both the hamburger icon and the logo are centered vertically in the nav, with the logo aligned to the left and the hamburger icon to the right;

Here's my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Maestoso Digital</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav id="nav">
            <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Maestoso Digital logo">
            <ul id="nav-links">
                <li id="active">Home</li>
                <li><a href="hosting.html">Hosting</a></li>
                <li><a href="cloud-management.html">Cloud Deployment</a></li>
                <li><a href="system-admin.html">System Administration</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form action="customers.html">
                <input id="customers-button" type="submit" value="Existing Customers" />
            </form>
        </nav>

        <main>
            <div id="header">
                <img id="header-img" src="img/header.png" alt="Picture of data centre">
                <h1 id="header-title">Welcome</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <h1>We are an internet service provider for the modern digital age!</h1>
                <p>Maestoso Digital is an internet service provider offering bespoke, enterprise-grade hosting solutions and system administration services for all, but especially for musicians and musical organisations. Our numerous datacenters around the globe offer ultra-fast performance for whatever your needs may be, and our Network Operations Centre monitor your services 24/7 to ensure that they are always online.</p>

                <footer>
                    <p>&copy; <a href="#">Maestoso Digital</a>. All rights reserved.</p>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Share+Tech&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Share Tech", sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ed15ac;
}

a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ed1c51;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 310px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

p, ul, li {
    font-size: 16pt;
}

#nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #nav {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        float: right;  
    }
  
    #nav a {float: left;}
  
    div#content {margin-left: 0; padding: 5px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #nav a {
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
    }
}


nav img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    padding-top: 20%;
    max-width: 150px;
}


#nav-links {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16pt;
}

#nav-links:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

p {
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-color: #1a1a1a;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-color: #000;
}

input {
    background-color: #ed15ac;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

input:hover {
    background-color: #ed1c51;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#header {
    position: relative;
}

#header-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 310px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 60%;
    font-size: 120px;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
}


footer {
    padding-top: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have tried everything that I can think of, and just can't get it to work. Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Yours, Antiquis

Comment: usually there's a bit of javascript involved to toggle a class to have the menu open/closed. You don't even have any html code in there for the hamburger toggle/button

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. I guess my best option would be to create a separate `div` containing the mobile nav containing the JS hamburger button, and then just using CSS to completely hide the main sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic example of a toggleable menu, but you need at least a little bit of javascript to toggle an `.open` class on your navigation container. The `.open` adds `display: block`, while by default in the mobile css it's `display:none` so the menu is hidden at first.

Or if you want to animate the appearance of the menu you'd be toggling the visibility and height instead for example - there are different implementations for this, I suggest inspecting other website's menu codes at a small viewport size to see how they've implemented their mobile navs for ideas.

I have not put these styles inside media queries in my example so you can clearly see it in action, and not have to resize the window.

```js
function navToggle() {
  document.getElementById('nav-links').classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Share+Tech&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Share Tech", sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ed15ac;
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ed1c51;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 310px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

p,
ul,
li {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#nav {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  padding-top: 20%;
  max-width: 150px;
}

#nav-links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#nav-links:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-color: #1a1a1a;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-color: #000;
}

input {
  background-color: #ed15ac;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

input:hover {
  background-color: #ed1c51;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
}

#header-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 310px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 60%;
  font-size: 120px;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
}

footer {
  padding-top: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}


/*for purposes of demonstration, normally you stick this code in a media query, hide the hamburger toggle on desktop! */

#nav-links {
  display: none;
}

#nav-links.open {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: right;
  }
  #nav a {
    float: left;
  }
  div#content {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #nav a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Maestoso Digital logo">
  <div class="hamburger-cont"><button id="hamburger-toggle" onclick="navToggle()">&#9776;</button></div>
  <ul id="nav-links">
    <li id="active">Home</li>
    <li><a href="hosting.html">Hosting</a></li>
    <li><a href="cloud-management.html">Cloud Deployment</a></li>
    <li><a href="system-admin.html">System Administration</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form action="customers.html">
    <input id="customers-button" type="submit" value="Existing Customers" />
  </form>
</nav>

<main>
  <div id="header">
    <img id="header-img" src="img/header.png" alt="Picture of data centre">
    <h1 id="header-title">Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h1>We are an internet service provider for the modern digital age!</h1>
    <p>Maestoso Digital is an internet service provider offering bespoke, enterprise-grade hosting solutions and system administration services for all, but especially for musicians and musical organisations. Our numerous datacenters around the globe offer
      ultra-fast performance for whatever your needs may be, and our Network Operations Centre monitor your services 24/7 to ensure that they are always online.</p>

    <footer>
      <p>&copy; <a href="#">Maestoso Digital</a>. All rights reserved.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Share+Tech&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Share Tech", sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ed15ac;
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ed1c51;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 310px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

p,
ul,
li {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#nav {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav-links {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.nav-links li {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.navigation a:hover,
.navigation a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

#hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.navigation .closebtn {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: right;
  }
  #nav a {
    float: left;
  }
  div#content {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  }
  #nav a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
  .navigation a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .navigation .closebtn {
    display: block;
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
  li {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  #nav-links {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40%;
  }
  #header {
    position: relative;
    top: 167px;
    left: -303px;
  }
}

nav img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  padding-top: 20%;
  max-width: 150px;
}

#nav-links {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#nav-links:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24pt;
  color: #000;
}

input {
  background-color: #ed15ac;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

input:hover {
  background-color: #ed1c51;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
}

#header-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 310px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 60%;
  font-size: 95px;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
}

footer {
  padding-top: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Maestoso Digital</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stack.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="nav">
    <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Maestoso Digital logo">
    <div id="myNav" class="navigation">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <ul id="nav-links">
        <li id="active">Home</li>
        <li><a href="hosting.html">Hosting</a></li>
        <li><a href="cloud-management.html">Cloud Deployment</a></li>
        <li><a href="system-admin.html">System Administration</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()" id="hamburger">&#9776;</span>

    <form action="customers.html">
      <input id="customers-button" type="submit" value="Existing Customers" />
    </form>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <div id="header">
      <img id="header-img" src="img/header.png" alt="Picture of data centre">
      <h1 id="header-title">Welcome</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <h1>We are an internet service provider for the modern digital age!</h1>
      <p>Maestoso Digital is an internet service provider offering bespoke, enterprise-grade hosting solutions and system administration services for all, but especially for musicians and musical organisations. Our numerous datacenters around the globe offer
        ultra-fast performance for whatever your needs may be, and our Network Operations Centre monitor your services 24/7 to ensure that they are always online.</p>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; <a href="#">Maestoso Digital</a>. All rights reserved.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "none";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not finding that this is working. Was this working on your system?